# C - Strange values while reading text file with fstream

Tags: c++, fstream, file-io

I wrote a function to read a text file, create an array from the integer values in the file and return the reference of that array to main function. The code I wrote(in VS2010):

```
//main.cpp
void main(){
int T_FileX1[1000]; 
    int *ptr=readFile("x1.txt");

    for(int counter=0; counter<1000; counter++)
        cout<<*(ptr+counter)<<endl;    
}
```

and the function is:

```
//mylib.h 
int* readFile(string fileName){
    int index=0;
            ifstream indata;
            int num;

    int T[1000];    
    indata.open("fileName");
            if(!indata){
                cerr<<"Error: file could not be opened"<<endl;
                exit(1);
            }
            indata>>num;
            while ( !indata.eof() ) { // keep reading until end-of-file
                T[index]=num;       
                indata >> num; // sets EOF flag if no value found
                index++;
            }
            indata.close();

            int *pointer;
            pointer=&T[0];
            return pointer;
}
```

the data in the file contains positive numbers like

```
5160
11295
472
5385
7140
```

When I write each value in "readFile(string)" function, it writes true. But when I wrote it to screen as U wrote in "main" function, it gives values strangely:

```
0
2180860
1417566215
2180868
-125634075
2180952
1417567254
1418194248
32   
2180736
```

irrelevant to my data. I have 1000 numbers in my file and I guess it raves these irrelevant values after a part of true writing. E.g. it writes first 500 values true, and then it writes irrelevant values to my data. Where is my fault?

Comment: You're reading garbage into num. It seems that what you want is to parse the strings representing numbers and convert them to integers.

Comment: @DiegoBasch.... wrong! The ifstream `operator >>` automatically parses the data according to destination data type.

Comment: `while ( !indata.eof() )` is incorrect. read more about the "EOF anti-pattern" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941 and http://drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php#4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int T[1000]; 
...
pointer=&T[0];
```

you are returning a pointer to a local stack variable which is going to get destructed.

I think what you want to do is to pass in the array `T_FileX1` that you have defined to the function and use that directly to read the data into.

Comment: It doesn't crash because he's only reading stack memory and dumping it to `cout` as numbers.  So there's no reason to crash, but the information on the stack is meaningless.

Comment: @MichaelBurr ah yes that makes sense, only a write would trigger a crash right?

Comment: Reading may cause a crash as well if you're using the information in some other way (such as a pointer or an index).

Answer (score 1):

You return a pointer to the first element of an array which is allocated on the stack and gets destroyed after your function returns. Try using a vector instead:

```
vector<int> readFile(string fileName) {
    ifstream indata;
    int num;

    vector<int> T;
    indata.open("fileName");
    if(!indata){
        cerr<<"Error: file could not be opened"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    indata>>num;
    while ( !indata.eof() ) { // keep reading until end-of-file
        T.push_back(num);
        indata >> num; // sets EOF flag if no value found
    }
    indata.close();

    return T;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of *undefined behavior*. You return a pointer to a local variable, when the function returns the part of the stack used by the function is no longer valid.

Pass the array as an argument to the function instead.